# How to fix android app bundle exported error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

Hi so I just want to release an update for my app and when I upload the app bundle to Google Play Console, I'm getting this error: [Error showing in Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNL4V.png)

and I saw some solutions for that. In that they are telling me add a line called `android:exported="true"` then they are telling me to look on merged manifest. here is mine: [Merged Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33beO.png) to see the log. It is showing me the same error in merged manifest. But I can't Solve it. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance. This is my manifest file: [Manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axBWH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GitHub-AlarmManger](https://github.com/zubairehman/AlarmManager) this library you're using (directly or through dependencies) has not been updated in a long time. the merged manifest is throwing the error from there. You can either fork the library and fix it yourself, or consider using a different library.

If you want to fork and fix:

1. Fork the library
2. Fix the manifest there
3. Go to [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/) and find your repo
4. Use it as a dependency